# How can I turn this function into a class in which the state would be an array containing the grid items?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to turn this function into a class because I would like to add more functionality. To do so I want to have the state be the grid containing all the swappable items, I am not exactly sure how to do this as I am fairly new to react. So any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swappable from './components/SwappableComponent'
import './App.css';
import DataTable from './components/tableWidget';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";


const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary
  }
});

function App(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='1' content={<DataTable/>}/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}> <Swappable id='2' content="#2"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='3' content="#3"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='4' content="#4"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
App.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

An exaple can be this, however, it's needs a bit more edit from your side:

```
class YourClassName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {

  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = props;

    return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='1' content={<DataTable/>}/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}> <Swappable id='2' content="#2"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='3' content="#3"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}><Swappable id='4' content="#4"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    something: state.something,
    something2: state.something2,
  };
}

const YourClassNameContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(YourClassName);

export default YourClassNameContainer;
```

Comment: What does the mapStateToProps do exactly? essentially what my end goal would be is to have the grid items as state and be able to remove if a button is pressed.